# Why host on different network connected to a switch are able to ping?

Tags: networking, routes, router, subnet

Hello Guys am a beginner,

I have two routers connected to a switch

```
R1 fa0/0 config - 10.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
R2 fa0/0 config - 20.1.1.1 255.255.255.0
```

both are configured as a host by "no ip routing"

and the fa0/0 interface of the router is connected to switch

I am able to ping R1 from R2 and vice-versa.

My question is, the routers  r1 and r2   supposed to communicate?

Answer (score 1):

It works because you have a switch connecting the 2 routers. In this scenario the ip addresses are useful for ARP protocol, that can find MAC addresses of the routers. After ARP resolution the switch will route Ethernet packets through network, form source to destination.

If you used a router instead of a switch, it wouldn't work,because the IPs belong to different subnets and routers route IP packets, not Ethernet packets.

Someone correct me if i am wrong.